# Tomcat application creates new session on page reload when visited through apache

Tags: session, google-chrome, apache2, cookies, tomcat6

We have a tomcat application which works fine in IE7/8 and Firefox. The only browser we are having issues with (that we care about at this point) is google Chrome. Users can navigate to the application fine and log in and do whatever they need to do in Firefox and IE. However, when trying to log in with Chrome, the session is apparently lost immediately after log in and when the authenticated user tries to navigate to another page they are bumped back to the log in page. This happens consistently.

I have seen other entries here and elsewhere that suggest that the context path might be to blame. I have tried setting a ProxyReverseCookiePath but that does not fix the problem.

Our virtual host configuration is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@email.com
    ServerName subdomain.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>


    ProxyPass /context/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/context/
    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/context/
    #ProxyPassReverse /context/ http://127.0.0.1:8009/context/
    #ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8009/context/
    #ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /context/ /

</VirtualHost>
```

There is another application deployed on the same instance of tomcat at the ROOT context. I have looked at the JSESSIONID that is set in the cookie, which is sent back to Chrome and it changes on every request, while it does not for IE and Firefox.

I am at a loss here. Any ideas are welcome!

We are using tomcat 6.0.23 as well as apache 2.2.14

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Tomcat 5.5 and Chrome 9.0.597.84 (same effect was with Chrome 8). What version have you been using?

Comment: My apologies for not realizing there was a response. Not sure if it is still relevant: I have no idea what version of Chrome it was that I was using at the time. tomcat was 6.0.23 and apache 2.2.14

Comment: @basZero:
It turned out that the browser would not always send the cookie to the server or the server would discard it if it thought the context path did not match. This here should do the trick. It does for me:

ProxyPass /context ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/context/
ProxyPassReverse /context/ http://127.0.0.1:2000/context/
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/context/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2000/context/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /context /

The last line ensures that the path written in the cookie is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For reference: The problem was solved by deploying the application at root context path and removing the context paths from the proxy statements.

```
ProxyPass /context/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
```

Nothing else was needed.